# Magento 2: Memcache causing issue on checkout payment page

Tags: magento2, checkout, onepage-checkout, authorize.net, memcache

I have installed Memcache on my server using WHM and add Memcache settings in **env.php** file by following the [Magento docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/memcache/memcache_magento.html). Also, test the [Memcache is running](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/memcache/memcache_centos.html).
But I am facing one issue here. When I place an order and make an online payment using Authorize.net.

**Scenario**

1. first time It works successfully.
2. When I tried again to place an order using on online payment. it redirects to checkout cart page with the empty cart.
3. When I flush the cache it works.
4. When I remove the **Memcache** settings from env.php. It works.

I googled to exclude cart and checkout page from Memcache. But didn't find any way to exclude these pages.

In Magento checkout module, the checkout_index_index.xml has already `cachable = false` in its block.

Please suggest.

Comment: have you find solution for this issue ?

Comment: I have updated the PHP version from 5.6 to 7 and use Memcached insted of  Memcache. It works for me.